# Криво работает php fast cgi

Tags: linux, apache2, docker, php5, php5-fpm

Поставил на ubuntu 14.04 в докере apache2 и php5 в режиме fast cgi по [этому гайду](https://www.vultr.com/docs/use-php5-fpm-with-apache-2-on-ubuntu-14-04).

В phpinfo все правильно отображает, но на многих страницах сверху пишется php код. А на некоторых выбивает "500 Internal Server Error".

Что делать?

---

Запуск apache2 и php5-fpm идет через supervisor.
Файл Supervisor:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:sshd]
command=/usr/sbin/sshd -D

[program:apache2]
command=/bin/bash -c "source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DF$

[program:php5-fpm]
command=/usr/sbin/php5-fpm
```

Comment: А при чём тут [tag:docker]?

Comment: @D-side Ну работает оно в докере все. Я конечно понимаю что оно не влияет по идеи но все же вы обязаны знать.

Comment: как вы запускаете `apache` и `php-fpm` внутри контейнера?

Comment: Докерфайл приложите что ли, раз такое дело :) Докер же про воспроизводимость.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Через Supervisor

Comment: с какими параметрами?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вот как тут https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/ 
Я туда еще php дописал 
[program:php5-fpm]
command = /usr/sbin/php5-fpm

Comment: про `apache` там есть. а про `php-fpm` — нет. приложите конфигурацию `supervisord` к тексту вопроса. внести изменения можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin приложил.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вижу две ошибки в конфигурации *supervisord*.

1. эта строка заканчивается непонятным образом (возможно, опечатка при вставке текста):

   ```
   command=/bin/bash -c "source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DF$
   ```

   должно быть:

   ```
   command=/bin/bash -c "source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND"
   ```
2. *php-fpm* надо запускать с опцией `-F`, чтобы процесс оставался работать в *foreground*, и *supervisord* не пытался вновь и вновь его [пере]запустить, обнаруживая что процесс завершился (с его, *supervisord*-а, точки зрения):

   ```
   command=/usr/sbin/php5-fpm -F
   ```

Comment: Исправил ошибки но "500 Internal Server Error" не пропал и ничего считайте не поменялось.

Comment: `$ docker logs ...` уже не выдаёт огромные простыни от *supervisord* о поястоянном перезапуске *php-fpm*? значит, теперь настало время смотреть логи.

Comment: ероров в логах нет.

Comment: уточняю: под «логами, которые следует посмотреть», я подразумевал логи *apache* и *php-fpm*.

Comment: Могу ли я вам написать вконтакте что бы я мог подробнее объяснить проблему и нюансы?

Comment: «вконтакте» — это такой сайт? нет, я там, конечно, не зарегистрирован. если вы хотите поделиться с кем-нибудь какой-то приватной информацией о логах вашего сайта, то, по-моему, вам лучше будет обратиться на какую-нибудь биржу фрилансеров.

Comment: Дело не в информации. Не совсем удобно сюда писать. Просмотрел логи в /var/log и там тоже нет ошибок.

Comment: если 500-ю ошибку выдаёт именно тот apache, что работает в данном контейнере, то в логах обязательно что-нибудь должно быть. возможно, они просто не ведутся. или в них попадает не вся необходимая для диагностики информация. или записываются не туда, где вы их ищете. те же соображения и по поводу *php-fpm*.

Comment: Если они не ведутся то как мне в таком случае поступать?

Comment: задать новый вопрос с помощью кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы.